# How to see all existing elements of a model in MySqlWorkbench?

Tags: synchronization, mysql-workbench, database-diagram

I work with MysqlWorkbench 6.3.10 and imported a view `kum_view_all_nuts-3-regions` from a database (source) to a model using the synchronization wizard.

> Database => Synchronize model...

I would expect the imported view to be shown in the `Catalog Tree` in the `Views` directory. However, I can not see it in the `Catalog Tree` (left part of the image) nor in the database diagram:

[image]

If I restart the synchronization, there are no changes for the view (see right part of the image). Therefore, the import must have been successful.

=>How can I see all elements of a model?

=>How can I add the existing view to an existing layer of the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

The views are shown correctly after **restarting** the MySqlWorkbench.

[image]

The elements that have no black dot in the Catalog Tree do not exist in the diagram yet. The views can be added to the diagram from the Catalog Tree by drag & drop.

Related bug report: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89841&thanks=4